# how to create tree looping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to achieve a loop with form of a Tree of 3 branches. So the result must be like This plan:

[image]

I try this but it only loop in the first branch

```
var n = 2 , h = 1 ;
 for (var i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++){
    document.write(i+' - ');
    while (h <= n){
      for (var j = 1 ; j <= 3 ; j++){
          document.write(j+' <br    /> ');
      }
      h++;
    }
    document.write(' <br    /> ');
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you give actual ideal output, not just a picture?

Comment: i want to output smth like that : (1 - 1 - 1) , (1 - 1 - 2) ,(1 - 1 - 3) ,(1 - 2 - 1) , (1 - 2 - 2)  , (1 - 2 - 3)  , (1 - 3 - 1) , (1 - 3 - 2)  , (1 - 3 - 3) and repeat this looping for the other 2 branches =>
(2 - 1 - 1) , (2 - 1 - 2) ... and (3 - 1 - 1) , (3 - 1 - 2) ...
The Idea of this looping is to make 3 branches as begin and for each branche add 3 more until n time !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following script should get the expected results. Instead of having a seprate variable for the count, I have used the iterator itself. See if the following will suffice.

```
            var n = 1
            for (var i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++){
                var j = 1
                while (j <= n){
                    for (;j <= 3 ; j++){
                        var k = 1
                        while (k <= j){
                            for (;k <= 3 ; k++){
                                document.write(i+' - '+ j +' - '+k +' <br    /> ');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            document.write(' <br    /> ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rest of the code is doing what your are expecting, you only need to set `h` back to 1 before the while statement

```
 var n = 2;
 for (var i = 1 ; i <= 3 ; i++){
    document.write(i+' - ');

    //here
    var h = 1
    while (h <= n){
      for (var j = 1 ; j <= 3 ; j++){
          document.write(j+' <br    /> ');
      }
      h++;
    }
    document.write(' <br    /> ');
```

Comment: there is a progress with that ! know the looping is in a line of branches for each first branche !

Comment: That solved the main question about the looping.  I'm not sure about what kind of formatting you are looking for so maybe you should have a look for a good HTML tutorial.

Comment: i want to output smth like that : (1 - 1 - 1) , (1 - 1 - 2) ,(1 - 1 - 3) ,(1 - 2 - 1) , (1 - 2 - 2) , (1 - 2 - 3) , (1 - 3 - 1) , (1 - 3 - 2) , (1 - 3 - 3) and repeat this looping for the other 2 branches => (2 - 1 - 1) , (2 - 1 - 2) ... and (3 - 1 - 1) , (3 - 1 - 2) ... The Idea of this looping is to make 3 branchs as begin and for each branch add 3 more  and 3 for each new branch until n time !